# Django-Filter Form Output Error Not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to display the search bar which when searched will display the entries of the form.

However It is not happening. I am using Django Filters to filter the form so that end customer will be able to search for the query and find the required details.

I am pasting the whole code below, If you think there is a better way than this to get the work done please do let me know.

I am also sharing the link of the Github repository incase if you would like to try and see the error.

I am stucked with this error from long time. NEED HELP VERY BADLY!!!!!

filters.py

```
import django_filters
from .models import *
from inventory_app.models import Form1


class ItemFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    item = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='item', lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Form1
        fields = ['item']
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
#from django.utils import timezone
# Create your models here.
class Form1(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    vendor = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    inward = models.IntegerField(default=1234)
    date = models.DateField()
    def __str__(self):
      return self.item
  #  security_stamp_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
```

Form1_entries.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} Form 1 Entries  {% endblock  %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
{% block body %} 
<div>
<form method="GET" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  {{myFilter.Form}}
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
</div>


{% for entry in entries %}
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      {{ entry.item }}     
      {{ entry.quantity }}
      {{ entry.vendor }}
      {{ entry.inward }}
      {{ entry.date }}
    </table>



{% endfor %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row p-5">
            <a href="/export/" class="btn btn-outline-primary" role="button">Download the CSV file</a>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

GITHUB repository:

https://github.com/samatharkar/altiostar

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from django.db.models import Q
>>> queryset = User.objects.filter(
    Q(first_name__startswith='R') | Q(last_name__startswith='D')
)
>>> queryset
<QuerySet [<User: Ricky>, <User: Ritesh>, <User: Radha>, <User: Raghu>, <User: rishab>]>
```

Comment: Can you tell me how and where do I need to put that in the code ?

Comment: its just example how to use Q function for searching something